# How can I run jshint in my CI using Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, makefile, azure-pipelines, jshint

I am trying to create a task in our Azure pipeline to validate our javascript.
We have a node container which performs an npm install when spun up:

```
  node:
    image: node:12-alpine
    user: "node"
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
    expose:
      - "8081"
    command: "npm install"
```

To perform my task I have created a make command in the Makefile:

```
js-check: ## Run Jshint
    docker-compose run node npm install && npm run jshint
```

Which I then call in the build job as follows:

```
- script: make js-check
            displayName: 'Run JSHint'
```

Locally when I call the make js-check it performs the install, followed by the jshint which outputs 0 vulnerabilities found. However when the pipeline reaches this task remotely it fails claiming missing write access to /home/node/app

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /home/node/app
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /home/node/app
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/home/node/app'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/home/node/app'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/node/app'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to checkout below solution. How did it go with you?

Answer (score 0):

Your Makefile runs two commands; the shell interprets the `&&` marker before it gets to Docker.  That command is equivalent to:

```
js-check: ## Run Jshint
        docker-compose run node npm install
        npm run jshint # (without Docker)
```

It looks like your environment already has Node installed.  You need to resolve the permissions issues (generally the CI system will check out source trees as a user that can run commands), and then you can use this native Node:

```
js-install: package.json
        npm install
js-check: js-install
        npm run jshint
```

This has the advantage of only depending on normal Javascript development tools; you don't need the extra `docker-compose.yml` file or administrator privileges just to run your unit tests.

If you really need to run this in Docker, you can either run this as two separate commands, or make the single container command be a shell that can interpret the `&&` itself:

```
js-install1: package.json docker-compose.yml
        docker-compose run node npm install
js-check1: js-install1
        docker-compose run node npm run jshint
```

```
js-check2: package.json docker-compose.yml
        docker-compose run node \
          sh -c "npm install && npm run jshint"
```

Answer (score 0):

Above error is because `/home/node` directory is owned by the node user in the default node image. The `/app` directory is created and owned by root. See this [open issue](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/740) about above error for more information.

I reproduced the same error with your compose file. When i changed the user to root. The error was gone.

So you can try changing the user to `root` instead of `node` in your compose file.

```
 node:
    image: node:12-alpine
    user: "root"
    working_dir: /home/node/app
```

As David pointed out, you also need to change your makefile to `docker-compose run node sh -c "npm install && npm run jshint"`. if you want to run the commands in docker.

Another workaround is to build and run your container from a dockerfile instead of the compose file. See below simple example dockerfile.

```
from node:12-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=development
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app 
RUN chown -R node:node /home/node/app
USER node
WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY . ./
RUN npm install
CMD [ "npm", "run", "jshint" ]
```

Then change the Makefile like example:

```
js-check: ## Run Jshint
    docker build --tag nodejshint:1.0 . && docker run --detach --name jshintContainer nodejshint:1.0
```